# estimating 3D Affine transformation, what matrix to use

Tags: image-processing, matrix, graphics, affinetransform, image-registration

I want to estimate an affine transform given matches between a transformed img and
 a reference img (which came from a reference stack).

Can I estimate a 3D affine transform given only the x,y coordinates of the transformed 
image and the x, y, z coordinates of the reference
image (z being the slice from the reference stack that the reference img came from)?

The general formula for illustrating a transform is:

`x' = M * x,` where `x'` is the transformed point. `M` is the transformation matrix, and `x` is the original point. The transform matrix, `M`, is estimated by multiplying `x'` by `inv(x)`.

The standard setup for estimating the 3D transformation matrix is this:
[image]

How can I **estimate the transformation matrix** if I don't have the `z'` of the transformed image? Is there some other setup I can use?

Comment: Does it really make sense to include the z-coordinate? After all, it will be equal for all pixels. Or do you want one transform for all images of the stack?

Comment: Do you want to find the 3Daffine transformation between a slicing of a 3D volume(meaning that the transform img goes through several different slices in the stack) if yes i thinkk you should give the points you find in the transform image z=1 but you find the best corresponds from all the points you find in the entire stack and not only from one slice.